# Tooltip hiding on click event

Tags: vb.net

I have a form with a tooltip shown in the form "shown event":

```
Private Sub frmMyFormWithToolTip_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        Dim tltStart As New ToolTip()
        Dim strMsgToolTip As String = "Lorem Ipsum"

        tltStart.IsBalloon = False
        tltStart.ToolTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Info
        tltStart.ShowAlways = False
        tltStart.UseFading = False
        tltStart.UseAnimation = False
        tltStart.AutoPopDelay = 1000
        tltStart.ToolTipTitle = "My Amazing ToolTip's Title"
        tltStart.Show(strMsgToolTip, cmbSiteUnit, 5000)

    End Sub
```

I'd like that this tooltip hides whenever and wherever users click. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You're creating a new ToolTip component (tltStart) and using another one (toolTip1) to show the tip? Use the one that you already have (toolTip1). Also, don't create a disposable object (ToolTip) like that. At least make it a class member, instantiate it and set the properties in the `Shown` event, and dispose of it in the `FormClosed` event.

Comment: Don't create the `ToolTip` in that method. Add it to your form in the designer and set all the relevant properties there. Only set properties in code if you don't know their value at design time. Just call `Show` in that event handler and then you can call `Hide` in whatever `Click` event handler(s) you want to. You would probably write a single event handler for the form and all its controls so that it doesn't matter where the click occurs.